# How To create thumbnails for a slider using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a custom Jquery Slider which have thumbnail navigation. I suceeded in creating the slider. But not with the thumbnail navigation.
Here is my code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var i = 0;
var m_height = $('main').height();
$('.test_bg').css('height', (function(){
        return m_height + 20;
    }));

    var doc_wid = $(document).width();
    if (doc_wid <= 768) {
        $('.test_bg').css('height','auto');
    }
$('.test_bg').append('<div class="thumbnails"></div>');
$('.thumbnails').append('<ul class="thumbnail_ul container"></ul>')
        var slide_array = $('.slide').toArray();
        var total_slide = $(slide_array).length;
        var img_path = "images/main-bg";

        var current_slide = slide_array[i];
        for(i=0; i<=total_slide; i++) {

            $('.thumbnail_ul').append('<li><a href="#"><img alt="slider"></a></li>');
            $('.thumbnail_ul li a img').attr('src', img_path + i + ".jpg");
        }


$('.slide').first().show();
  }
```

And my Html Markup

```
    <div class="test_bg">
        <img class="slide active" src="images/main-bg1.jpg">
        <img class="slide" src="images/main-bg2.jpg">
        <img class="slide" src="images/main-bg3.jpg">
        <img class="slide" src="images/main-bg4.jpg">
        <img class="slide" src="images/main-bg5.jpg">
        <img class="slide" src="images/main-bg6.jpg">
        <img class="slide" src="images/main-bg7.jpg">
    </div>
```

And Css

```
    .test_bg { position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:70px; left:0; z-index:-99;}
    .test_bg img { width:100%; height:100%;}
    .slide {display:none;}
    .thumbnails { position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100px; float:left;}
    .thumbnail_ul { /*float:left; width:100%;*/ height:100px; padding:0; overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden;}
    .thumbnail_ul li { float:left; list-style:none; height:100px; width:140px; padding:10px; border:3px solid #ffffff; cursor:pointer;}
    .thumbnail_ul li a { text-decoration:none; float:left; width:100%;}
    .thumbnail_ul li a img { float:left; width:100%;}
```

And now what i get in the thumbnail is the last image of array repeated to the total number of slides. please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is with this code: `$('.thumbnail_ul li a img').attr('src', img_path + i + ".jpg");`. You are changing every `img` in the thumbnail in each loop with your selector `'.thumbnail_ul li a img'`.

Just do:

```
$('.thumbnail_ul').append('<li><a href="#"><img alt="slider" src="'+img_path + i +'.jpg"></a></li>');
```

You can further improve your code using [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

```
$('.test_bg').append('<div class="thumbnails"><ul class="thumbnail_ul container"></ul></div>');

var img_path = "images/main-bg";

$('.slide').each(function(i){
  $('.thumbnail_ul').append('<li><a href="#"><img alt="slider" src="'+img_path + i +'.jpg"></a></li>');
});
```

Edit:

If you just want to use the same image `src` value with your thumbnails, just retrieve it so you don't need to worry about the index.

```
$('.slide').each(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  $('.thumbnail_ul').append('<li><a href="#"><img alt="slider" src="'+src+'"></a></li>');
});
```